# express can't get after posting

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, vue.js

I'm writing a web application with Vue.js and Express and MongoDB. Express server has two routes which the Vue client will use:  POST: /post; GET: /post; The first one is to publish a post, and another one is to get posts;

When I publish a post(client beg POST /post); The post was published successfully, and then the client go to the first page to get posts(client beg GET /post), but the server error:' Can't set headers after they are sent.', I have to restart the server, and then all work well, the post published just now is shown normally.

I have tried a lot, but I can't solve it, I need your help.

the /post router of express:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var Post = require('../models/post');
var moment = require('moment');
var jwt = require("jwt-simple");

router.get('/',function(req,res,next){
    Post.get(function(err,posts){
        if(err){
           res.status(404);
           res.end();
        }
    res.status(200);
    res.json({
        posts:posts
    });
  });
});
  router.post('/',function(req,res,next){
      var token = req.body.access_token;
      if(token){
      try{
        var decoded = jwt.decode(token,req.app.get('jwtTokenSecret'));
        if(decoded.exp < Date.now()){
            console.log("haha")
            res.end('token expired',401);
        }
        //console.log(decoded)
         var newPost = new Post({
            name:decoded.iss,
            title:req.body.title,
            content:req.body.content
        });
        console.log(newPost);
        newPost.save(function(err,post){
            if(err){
                console.log("publish failed");
                res.status(500);
                res.send({error:1});
            }
            console.log('publish done');
        });
        res.status(200);
        res.send({});
    } catch(err){
        res.status(401);
        res.send('no token');
    }
 }
});
module.exports = router;
```

Comment: Seems like a logical flaw, you're doing `res.send({});` regardless of what happens in the `newPost.save()` function, but if that fails, you're trying to set the `status` header again, but you can't, as the headers are already sent and you've started outputting outside the async `save()` function.

Comment: I just modify it to res.end() ,but the same error

Comment: newPost.save() runs well, it comes error when GET '/post'

Comment: Well, the `GET` route does the same thing, if it errors out, it tries to set the `status` header twice.

Comment: now I found that the error comes from Post.get(); but I don't konw why, because it works while I restart the server. Could you please have a look at my code on github, the address is :github.com/laoqiren/vue-express-forum thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your route to do

```
router.get('/',function(req,res,next){
    Post.get(function(err,posts){
        if(err){
           res.status(404);
           res.end();
        } else {
           res.status(200);
           res.json({
                posts:posts
           });
        }
    });
});

router.post('/', function(req, res, next) {
    var token = req.body.access_token;
    if (token) {
        var decoded = jwt.decode(token, req.app.get('jwtTokenSecret'));
        if (decoded.exp < Date.now()) {
            console.log("haha")
            res.end('token expired', 401);
        } else {
            var newPost = new Post({
                name: decoded.iss,
                title: req.body.title,
                content: req.body.content
            });

            newPost.save(function(err, post) {
                if (err) {
                    console.log("publish failed");
                    res.status(500);
                    res.send({error: 1});
                } else {
                    res.status(200);
                    res.send({});
                }
            });
        }
    } else {
        res.status(401);
        res.send('no token');
    }
});
module.exports = router;
```

Or return in the error clause, otherwise it will try to set the `status` header twice, the last time after output has been generated.

Comment: now I found that the error comes from Post.get(); but I don't konw why, because it works while I restart the server. Could you please have a look at my code on github, the address is :https://github.com/laoqiren/vue-express-forum      thanks a lot

Comment: It seems like that it comes error when the server trying to open mongodb after the post is publised successfully, but the GET '/post' does not catch it

Comment: Your `/post` route has the same issue, multiple `send` followed by attempts to set the headers. I'll post both routes fixed.

Comment: I have modify them like the code above, but the Post.get() runs error. The mongodb can't be open when it goes to GET '/post'

Comment: But when I restart server, the GET 'post' runs well

Comment: Then I don't know, you're doing something wrong when quering the database if it errors out, but this should fix the "headers already sent" error, unless you're trying to set headers other places as well.

Comment: thanks a lot , I think I have to sleep now, thanks for your help